# RCNN with TimeDistributed for Video Classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I need of a RCNN structure to classify videos after extract frames with OpenCV. I've readed about and searched a lot for this structure, and reached this model in Keras:

```
model = Sequential([

#Visual features learning
TimeDistributed(Conv2D(units=128, kernel_size=5, strides=1, input_shape(28, 28, 1))),
TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)),
Dropout(0.25),

TimeDistributed(Conv2D(units=256, kernel_size=5, strides=1)),
TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)),
Dropout(0.25),

TimeDistributed(Conv2D(units=128, kernel_size=5, strides=1)),
TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)),
Dropout(0.25),

TimeDistributed(Conv2D(units=128, kernel_size=5, strides=1)),
TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)),
Dropout(0.25),

#Flatten
TimeDistributed(Flatten()),

#LSTM for sequence learning
LSTM(units, activation, recurrent_activation, use_bias),

#FC
Dense(units=500, activation='relu'),
Dropout(0.25),
Dense(units=4, activation='softmax')

])
```

I could adapt this structure (or use it directly) to learn features from image data and time with the LSTM layer?
If not, how i have to adapt this module correctly?

OBS: The hyperparameters in this example is just for, obviously, an example. I still have to find a manner to parametrize the LSTM layer to make it work.

Thanks for the support!

Comment: ask what you want to do 
what is input
what is purpose
what is output

Comment: I will extract frames of a video with OpenCV, then train the model to classify activity in those image frames through time, so, classify an activity in a video, the input would be the frames.

Answer (score 1):

use ConvLSTM2D 
like this example 
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/conv_lstm.py
but change end of model with classification layers

or use prebuild model  use it to encode features of frames
feed this featureas within certain time step to the LSTM 
then at the end make classification

Comment: So, based on this example  https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/conv_lstm.py i have to change the last 'Conv3D' layer to a classification layer, right?